# SVN checkout/commit in Netbeans not working

Tags: svn, netbeans

When I would like to checkout or commit from/to SVN this window opens and do nothing.

Sometimes it shows my login credentials, but it's just in 1 of 50. But after that it's working. 
When I click on Next, only a warning shows, that the URL is empty. But after that nothing, only the Cancel works.

What can I do?

The window is like this: 
[image: SVN Picture]

Comment: Are you specifying the URL to your repository?

Comment: I cannot write anything there, it's grey.

Answer (score 0):

This is checklist:

**1.** Check **config SVN connection** in Netbeans IDE.
**2.** Althought  you can login by your user account to server, check particular ***user permission on particular directory*** (folder in server).
**3.** Netbeans also notice that: "URL is empty", You ***check URL repository exist*** status.
**4.** SVN server ***connection***.

Comment: It is not about the server, it is about the local config of the NetBeans. I just reinstalled, and now it works. But on my other computer the bug(?)  it's still there. I think its about a large amount of active projects. But I dont want to close projects, there is a work on them.